# {To verb 1 + verb 2} or {to verb 1 + **to** verb 2}?

Tags: verbs, infinitives

How to have two "to + verbs"? Is it to verb 1 + verb 2 or to verb 1 + to verb 2?

1. Lead a team to integrate two systems and increase the accuracy of report.
2. Lead a team to integrate two systems and to increase the accuracy of report.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't happen to be from a résumé, does it? I ask, because bullet points in résumés tend to be in past tense, in which case the first verb would be **led**.

Comment: Version 1 is ambiguous.  The conjunction "and" could be joining "integrate" with "increase" (as you intended), or it could be joining "lead" to "increase".  That is, the two activities could be (1) Lead a team to integrate two systems and (2) increase the accuracy of report.

Comment: Neither is correct in English. Could you find a better translator?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Lead a team to integrate two systems and increase the accuracy of report.

Version 1. is the better option.

Version 2. is acceptable but not recommended.

Note that adding extra words and clauses can make a difference, so:

*Lead a team to integrate two systems and **also** to increase the accuracy of report.*

This is because the addition of extra words can change the emphasis and stress pattern of a sentence and, if a long passage is added, it might be necessary to remind the reader that the latest verb is still an infinitive.

Comment: You're right about the importance of the stress pattern for the real-time parser, but keeping separate complementizer _to_ isn't merely "acceptable"; it's perfectly normal. Who knows, after all, what degree of separation from it will cause a listener to forget the main verb? For precision, deletions are discouraged -- especially in writing -- because every deletion leaves out information that would rule out many unintended ambiguous readings.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I don't disagree with your comments. My dismissal of version 2 wasn't intended to imply a general rule.  I was responding specifically to that single case with a rider to be wary.

Comment: @JohnLawler What's the grammatical relationship of the two infinitives with "Lead a team..."?

Comment: These are both purpose infinitives, which means you can insert _in order_ before _to_ without changing meaning. Since they're both purpose infinitives, it makes sense to drop the second _to_ if the first clause is short; if it's long, though, a reminder might be in order.

Answer (score 0):

In sentence 1, the two actions appear clubbed together in a single unit.

Sentence 2 seems to distinguish between them as two distinct actions.

Use whichever leads to more clarity.